# Blazor: Close MatBlazor PopUp Dialog box after Login success in Child Component

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, matblazor

I have a **Login.razor** the page where all the action happens.

```
@page "/login"
@inject IAuthService AuthService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@if (ShowErrors)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <p>@Error</p>
    </div>
}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <EditForm Model="loginModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleLogin">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <InputText Id="email" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="loginModel.Email" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => loginModel.Email)" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <InputText Id="password" type="password" Class="form-control" @bind-Value="loginModel.Password" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => loginModel.Password)" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    private LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
    private bool ShowErrors;
    private string Error = "";

    private async Task HandleLogin()
    {
        ShowErrors = false;

        var result = await AuthService.Login(loginModel);

        if (result.Successful)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
        else
        {
            Error = result.Error;
            ShowErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And my **MainLayout.razor** contains the Matblazor dialog popup.

```
<MatDialog @bind-IsOpen="@signInOpen">
    <MatTabGroup>
        <MatTab Label="SIGN IN">
            <BlazorCom.Client.Pages.Login />
        </MatTab>
    </MatTabGroup>
</MatDialog>

@code
{
    public bool signInOpen = false;

    void OpenDialog()
    {
        signInOpen = true;
    }
}
```

When I log in using this dialog box the box doesn't close on its own as I have no idea how to do that.
Now I want to close the Popup dialog box after a successful login.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: You might like https://mudblazor.com it is a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `signInOpen` to false and the dialog will close.

Edit: If you need to set it from the outside add a method Close like this:

```html
@code {

public void CloseDialog() {
  signInOpen=false;
  StateHasChanged();
}
```

Then in Login.razor you can call the CloseDialog() function in the @onclick event of the submit button.

Comment: How can I set signInOpen to false from the Login.razor page?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to set it from outside.

Comment: I want to close the popup on a successful submit. Not just by clicking the submit button. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Yes, in your HandleLogin  method when result.Successful is true call CloseDialog() on the dialog. Use @ref to get hold of the Dialog reference so you can call CloseDialog() on it. And of course you need to find a way to pass the dialog into the Login component. Or you use an EventCallBack to let the Main know that the login was successful and close the dialog there. That's probably better.